# Cognito can sign out the old user but not the new ones

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, session, jwt, amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito to sign up/sign in user/ sign out user with my Django App, however, Cognito can sign out the old users but not the new ones, so basically when user sign up today, and log in. The session wouldn't expire at all( not logging out) even though its specified on the Client App to log users out every 5 minutes when inactive as it's a payment app.
it's very wired that old users's session token is expired every 5 minutes but not the new users?

Comment: Are you using the hosted UI?

Comment: Reactjs for UI, Django for the backend

Comment: No I mean are you using one of the OAuth flows (the hosted UI) or are you using the cognito-identity sdk to authenticate?